# Recursions for the A111528

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, integer-sequences, recurrences

Let $T(n,k)$ be [A111528](https://oeis.org/A111528) i.e. square table, read by antidiagonals, where the g.f. for row $n+1$ is generated by
$$
xg_{n+1}(x) = \frac{1}{n+1}\left(1+nx - \frac{1}{g_n(x)}\right), \\
g_0(x) = \sum\limits_{n\geqslant0} n!x^n.
$$
Let
$$
P(n, k, m) = P(n-1, k, m) + P(n-1, k-1, m), \\
P(n, n, m) = 1, \\
P(n, 0, m) = m
$$
Here $P(n, 0, m) = m$ for $n>0$.

Let
$$
R_1(n, q, m) = (q + m + 1)R_1(n-1, q+1, m) + \sum\limits_{j=0}^{q} R_1(n-1, j, m), \\
R_1(0, q, m) = 1
$$
Let
$$
R_2(n, q, m) = R_2(n-1, q+1, m) + \sum\limits_{j=0}^{q} P(q+2, j+1, m)R_2(n-1, j, m), \\
R_2(0, q, m) = 1
$$

I conjecture that $$R_1(n, 0, m) = R_2(n, 0, m) = T(m, n+1).$$

Here is the PARI/GP prog to check it numerically:

```
upto1(n, m) = my(v1, v2, v3); v1 = vector(n + 1, i, 1); v2 = v1; v3 = vector(n + 1, i, 0); v3[1] = 1; for(i = 1, n, for(q = 0, n - i, v2[q + 1] = (q + m + 1)*v1[q + 2] + sum(j = 0, q, v1[j + 1])); v1 = v2; v3[i + 1] = v1[1]); v3
upto2(n, m) = my(v1, v2, v3, v4); v1 = vector(n + 1, i, 1); v2 = v1; v3 = vector(n + 1, i, 0); v3[1] = 1; v4 = vector(n + 2, i, vector(i, j, if(j == i, 1, if(j == 1, m)))); for(i = 3, n + 2, for(j = 2, i - 1, v4[i][j] = v4[i-1][j] + v4[i-1][j-1])); for(i = 1, n, for(q = 0, n - i, v2[q + 1] = v1[q + 2] + sum(j = 0, q, v4[q + 3][j + 2]*v1[j + 1])); v1 = v2; v3[i + 1] = v1[1]); v3
test(n, m) = upto1(n, m) == upto2(n, m)
```

Is there a way to prove it?